# NameError: name 'Label' is not defined - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What this code does is, when I paste a link something like this: `http://url.io/s/1233abca/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contens%2F` then it will change to: `exmaple.com/some_contents/`

[image: This] 
This code works just fine (I set the text "Link" in row 1):

```
from tkinter import *
from urllib import parse
from tkinter import Tk

window = Tk()

window.title("Link Slicer")

window.geometry('344x50')

lbl = Label(window, text="Link")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)

txt = Entry(window,width=50)

txt.grid(column=0, row=0)

def clicked():

    sliced = txt.get()

    sliced = parse.unquote(sliced)

    lbl.configure(text= sliced[36:])

    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(sliced[36:])
    r.update()

btn = Button(window, text="Slice", command=clicked)

btn.grid(column=1, row=0)



window.mainloop()
```

[image: this]

but I'm getting  error with this code (I just want to put the text "Link" in row 1 just like the first one:

```
import tkinter as tk
from urllib import parse

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Link Slicer")
root.geometry('344x50')
root.attributes("-topmost", True)

lbl = Label(root, text="Link")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)

def clicked():
    clip = root.clipboard_get()
    clip = parse.unquote(clip)[36:]

    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(clip)
    entry_text.set(clip)
    lbl.configure(text= clip)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Slice", command=clicked)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What the **first code** does is when I paste a link like this: `http://url.io/s/1233abca/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contens%2F` and click the button... then the "Link" text (in row 1) will change to the "sliced" output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbNk4.png).

However, in the **second code**, when I copy a link like this: `http://url.io/s/1233abca/?s=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsome_contens%2F` and click the "slice" button (no need the paste to entry field), then the output will show in the entry field.

What I'm trying to do now is, using the **second code**, but instead of the output being displayed in the entry field, instead, it will change the text "Link" (just like in the first code).

Comment: Please paste _all_ relevant error messages and _only the relevant code_ as text into your question.

Comment: Your first example does `from tkinter import *`, but your second one doesn't. That's why your first example can access `Label` but your second one can't.

Comment: Your second one does `import tkinter as tk` instead. Which is fine, but then you have to use `tk.Label`, just like you use `tk.Tk` and `tk.Button`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported `Label`. Add `from tkinter import *` back to your code.